# How do I create a vpn over another vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am in a network that for accessing internet we must connect to vpn. also there exist another service for special bandwith for some users. So for accessing this service I must create another vpn. But when I try to connect this vpn, the connection of vpn server disconnected. Is there a way to create a vpn over another vpn -two vpn over

Comment: Depending on the particular VPN technology used, it may be impossible. You cannot, for instance, tunnel IPSEC over IPSEC (at least not on Linux), and some kinds of TCP encapsulation interfere with other types of TCP encapsulation. What kind of VPNs are the two?

Answer (score 2):

From my testing NetworkManager (using nmcli) only supports one VPN connection at a time. You will need to write a script that manually invokes openvpn and place it in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`. The script will need to query networkmanager to see if your other VPN connection has been made.

I wrote a script that automatically starts my VPN connection under certain conditions, maybe you can use it as a [starting place](https://github.com/wl-net/vpn-connector).

Also, keep a close watch on your routing table. If you start a VPN while connected to another one, it could redirect traffic from the first VPN, disrupting both VPN connections.